# Setting math fonts in Beamer

Tags: fonts, math-mode, beamer

Is it possible to only change the math font in Beamer with XeLaTeX? The only partial solution I've been about to find is to create a new command:

```
\renewcommand\mathfamilydefault{\rmdefault}
```

The above command does essentially what I want, but it also strangely inserts characters (`lmr`) prior to maths. For example,

```
\mathfamilydefault{${x}_{ij} = -d_{k}/d_{0}$},
```

yields:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

there is no need for using that macro inside your text. It is an internal definition and has the value `lmr`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand\mathfamilydefault{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}
${x}_{ij} = -d_{k}/d_{0}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easy way to get this behavior inside the equation environment? I see that inside the equation environment, Beamer defaults to non-math fonts.

Comment: I do not understand what you really want?? It is valid inside the math expression and _not_ outside

Comment: Your solution is perfect. My follow-up question was: How can I change math fonts within the equation environment? I've noticed that when working with this environment the default font is non-math.

Answer (score 19):

I think you can use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}

Hello world!

${x}_{ij} = -d_{k}/d_{0}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there is also the option `stillsansserifmath`

Comment: \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} Plus $10^10^100$ on that. Awesome - looks so much better.

Comment: This has no effect for me. Using xelatex.

Comment: @Marcel I get _exactly_ the same output with XeLaTeX. I am afraid a MWE is needed...